# Determining if a function is harmonic in some subset of the plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Determine if the function $f(x,y) = \ln(\|(x,y)\|)$ is harmonic in some subset of the plane.

So knowing that from the Laplacian $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = 0 $$

I could determine if its harmonic I went to compute the second-order partials and got that

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} - \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 0 $$

This resulted in $2y^2-2x^2=0$

I'm not sure I follow how I can find the subset of the plane here? Restricting $x$ and $y$ somehow?

Comment: You miscalculated. The correct calculation gives harmonicity (outside the origin) directly. It's easier to see [provided one has some background in complex analysis] that (modulo canonical identifications) $f$ is the real part of branches of the logarithm.

Comment: I haven't taken a complex analysis class... Where might I have made a mistake?

Comment: Ah apparrently on the second-order partial wrt to $y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've edited the question with the correct calculation I think. I still don't quite see the subset for the plane...

Comment: You have a sign error. Due to the symmetry of $f$, if $$g(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)\,,$$ then $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y) = g(y,x)$. Now with $g(x,y) = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ you get $g(x,y) + g(y,x) = 0$ (on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$).